# How Can I Copy a Video to iPhone and Send It Over iMessage?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios

I'm trying to send to video I made with my previous Windows Phone over iMessage, but after syncing it to my phone with iTunes, it shows up as a movie.

I can't select it from the messaging app, because I can only select items from `Pictures > Video`.

How can I get it to show up in there?

Video details:

```
Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                       : mp42
File size                      : 22.3 MiB
Duration                       : 17s 740ms
Overall bit rate               : 10.6 Mbps

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : Main@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames      : 1 frame
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 17s 740ms
Source duration                : 17s 773ms
Bit rate mode                  : Variable
Bit rate                       : 10.4 Mbps
Width                          : 1 280 pixels
Height                         : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Variable
Frame rate                     : 29.821 fps
Minimum frame rate             : 6.944 fps
Maximum frame rate             : 30.364 fps
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.380
Stream size                    : 22.1 MiB (99%)
Source stream size             : 22.1 MiB (99%)
mdhd_Duration                  : 17770

Audio
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                 : LC
Codec ID                       : 40
Duration                       : 17s 740ms
Source duration                : 17s 740ms
Bit rate mode                  : Constant
Bit rate                       : 96.0 Kbps
Channel count                  : 1 channel
Channel positions              : Front: C
Sampling rate                  : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 214 KiB (1%)
Source stream size             : 214 KiB (1%)
mdhd_Duration                  : 17740
```

Comment: What format is the video in?

Comment: @patrix I've updated the question with technical details.

Answer (score 1):

Because the video was only 22MB I was able to use Gmail to send it to myself (where it strangely became 30MB).

After opening the attachment from the email app, it began to play, but I noticed it had the sharing icon so I was able to send it over iMessage from there.

[image: iOs hare icon]

However, I would still like a general solution for larger files.

Comment: maybe use a cloud service. the size on the email is bigger because of base64 encoding

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to import it into iPhoto in order to sync it to your iPhone's picture folder and be able to share via iMessage. The steps would be:

1. Import into iPhoto, for example by dragging the video to it's icon in the dock
2. Sync the Video to your iPhone with iTunes by selecting the event which was automatically created in/by iPhoto. If there isn't an event created automatically, you'd need to create one or  put that video in an album. Any "folder" in iPhoto which is able to be synced by iTunes should do the job.
3. Now it should appear in your pictures app on the iPhone and you should be able to share it via iMessage

Hope that helps